# Excel treats numbers with letters different from numbers, even though the format is the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have numbers such as 4BU that are treated properly by this formula:

```
=IF($B8<>"";VLOOKUP("*"&$B8&"*";Sheet1!$A:$J;1;FALSE);"")
```

If it finds the number, it shows it

But I also have numbers like 578, that only output #N/A. They are all formatted as Text(both B8 and A:J in this example), yet they are not treated the same.

I noticed that numbers without letters work when I take the wildcards out of the formula, but that makes the formula useless. How do I fix this?

Comment: "They are all formatted as Text" - which one? B8 or A:J? Could you please upload some sample screenshots to help us understand your issue?

Comment: Both B8 and A:J are formatted as text. My workplace doesn't allow screenshots of our Excel sheets, sorry

Comment: Without sample data and screenshot we can't really understand your question, therefore can't help you with it. If your company doesn't allow it, than hopefully you have IT support helping you to solve this.

Comment: I can give examples, just no screenshots. I have a sheet, in the second column of the sheet I input inventory numbers. The inventory number is for example in B8, now the formula above is taking B8 and searches in a sheet with all inventory numbers (Sheet1!A:J) if the inventory number is in there. If it is, it puts the number, if not, it puts out an empty string. The issue is that this formula can't deal with inventory numbers that don't contain letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in Array format:

```
=IF($B8<>"";INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$J100;MATCH("*"&$B8&"*";Sheet1!$A1:$A100&"";0);1);"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be conformed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter insted of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Also being an Array formula the references need to be limited to the data set and not the whole column.  I referenced only the first 100 rows, change that to your data set.

Answer (score 1):

Your VLookup formula

=IF($B8<>"";VLOOKUP("*"&$B8&"*";Sheet1!$A:$J;1;FALSE);"")

Is searching for a **string** that contains whatever is in cell B8. As you have found out, a number is not a string. It is still not a string if you format it as text. You can test this by changing the value in the lookup table from `578` to `'578`, you should now be able to find it by entering `578` (or a subset like `78`) in cell B8.

If you don't have the option of modifying all the numbers in the lookup table, the only solution I can think of is to have a separate column that contains a copy of column A converted to a string. For example, in column K of Sheet1 you could create a copy of column A with an empty string appended. Enter `=$A1&""` in cell K1, and copy it down. Now change your `VLOOKUP` to search column K instead of A.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, but it did not work as intended

Comment: @M.Pet I realise that I accidentally left off the last sentence which is to search the column with the modified value (column K) instead of the original value (column A). When I do this it works for me.

Comment: I was able to modify my original column with the character, but that did not work out. The formula still only out put #N/A